# What is reason of having 3 phase in the transmission in cities?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, batteries, current

What is the reason of having 3 transmission lines as three phases ? 
[image]

Comment: It saves a wire. (By the way it is not only in the cities.)

Comment: Sorry my English is bad. I meant why they are not using single phase instead of three ?

Comment: As I said: it saves a (return) wire. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-phase_electric_power)

Comment: Torque and current on 3 phase are far smoother for motors than 1 phase and that means more reliable , less expensive maintenance from less vibration and better torque performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electricity is generated as three-phase, for very good reasons that I won't go into here, and if you distributed only one of those phases, then you have what's called an unbalanced load (in fact, it's about as unbalanced as you can possibly get), and power people *hate* those--they cause all kinds of problems with power distribution and--don't quote me on this--i'm pretty sure they can even damage generation equipment when they're really bad.

So instead, you distribute all three phases and just do single-phase (or split-phase) in each individual building.

(I'm a bit rusty on power transmission, so please feel free to correct any mistakes or misrepresentations in this answer!)

Comment: Oh ok, I got it. So for power transmission quality purposes, it has to be three phases. But for homes, they use single phase to them

Comment: Right. Different buildings will be on different phases, too, to try to keep the load close to balanced.

Comment: Not always. many house has three phases for the electric cooker.

Comment: @Oldfart Good point; three phase is used in some houses and especially industrial buildings. I left that out because I didn't want to muddle the point, though, which is that three phase is used primarily for transmission, and most of what you see in buildings (whether residential or offices or whatever) is single-phase, but usually a different phase from the neighbors.

Comment: @Hearth but what do you mean when u balancing the load?

Comment: I really appreciate you all for explaining

Comment: @f321 A balanced load is one that results in equal magnitude current on all three phases, with the currents mutually 120° out of phase with each other.

Answer (score 4):

### It's the most efficient way to transmit AC

Let's say you are running 200A wires insulated for 5000 volts, for a nice round 1 MW capacity per wire one-way.

If you run single-phase, you need 2 wires to complete the loop, and you get 1.0 MW circuit capacity.

If you run 2-phase 90 degrees, you need 4 wires and get 2.0 MW circuit capacity.

If you run 3-phase "delta", you need 3 wires and get 1.732 MW capacity.

This is the most economical use of wire and terminations.

### It simplifies life for motors and DC loads

People who run motors love you, because 3-phase is the most efficient motor design, and it's fully able to self-start without burdensome compromises.

You love people who are driving DC loads (i.e. rectifying 3-phase) because there's *considerably less* ripple between the most positive and most negative pole of 3-phase. This means things that ultimately use DC have much better Power Factors with less harmonics and inductive heating. (when you try to push a 300Hz harmonic through a 60Hz transformer).

### That drawing is wrong

The power on the top 3 wires is 3-phase delta.  There is no neutral here.  That wire labeled neutral is conspicuous in its absence of any insulators. **It is a guy wire**.  Note how the transformers are on the pole *out of balance*, their weight is pulling the pole over to the right.  Note also how the two down-guys are also pulling the pole over to the right.  Everything is teaming up to make this pole fall over, right?  No.

The upper conductors are probably [ACSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium-conductor_steel-reinforced_cable) which means they have the dual role of also being in physical tension.  Those, and the lower cross-guy, are counter-balancing something that is happening on the pole to the left, off-picture.

Given the bottom-tier insulators, I presume the lower lines are 480 "wye" service, with 480V corner-corner and 277V corner-neutral.

"Why does neutral need insulation? It's near ground."  No, it's only near ground if everything is working properly.  The rest of the time, lookout!  That is why the lower service conductors do in fact have the same insulator on neutral as hot.

Answer (score 1):

The key reason why 3 phases are generated and distributed is: to provide a solid rotational power for electric motors. Two phases 90* shifted would theoretically be enough, but the 3-phase system probably provides for smoother operation of the motors. Theoretically also more robust (fault tolerant) but in practice the 3-phase motors don't like a missing phase very much.

The fact that when the load is evenly spread across three phases, the return wire gets hardly any load, that's merely a "fringe benefit", a desired optimal state of things. And it's true that with a 2-phase 90*-shifted system, this "balance around the neutral return" would not be achievable.

Another fringe benefit is that, when you need some non-trivial DC power, 3-phase rectification gives you smoother DC output, even without heavy capacitive filtering (though without PFC, the harmonic content is certainly ugly even that way). In this vein, I've read that HVDC transmission systems (when converting from AC to DC) and some railway power rectifier stations can employ phase-shifting transformers to produce 6 phases (shifted by 60 degrees) to produce an even smoother rectified output...

The three single-phase transformers are interesting. I'm used to seeing pole-mounted [3-phase transformers](https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/three-phase-transformer-1124361728).

Comment: Info only: 3 phase is the most efficient energy transmission choice. Fewer or more phases result in higher overall costs for a range of competing reasons.

Comment: I think in practice a two phase motor would only be slightly harder to build that a three phase on.  But in a two phase supply, the "neutral" line actually has to carry *more* current than either of the "power" wires.  So you need three wires.  And if you have three wires, you may as well make them equal sized and use three phase.

Comment: @TimWescott Yes. 2 phase motors exist. Everything is a compromise, but 3 phase less so overall than anything else. When you get a rotor with an even number of slots and not divisible by 3 eg 10 slots or 14 (people are annoying :-) ) you can get a reasonable result from 2 phase - with proportionally lower speed by a factor of N/2 . I looked at doing just that recently t make use of low cost laminations. We do this with 1 phase motors where you COULD get say 2900 RPM at 50 Hz (& some specialist applications do) but the compromise we mostly choose is ~= 1450 RPM (1500 RPM with 50 RPM "slip").